# How can you write double max = a [0] < b [0] ? B [0] : a [0]; in a normal if else sentence in the programming language c?

Tags: c, testing, syntax

I'm struggling to code it correctly, can someone please help me. Much appreciated!

How can you write `double max = a [0] < b [0] ? B [0] : a [0];` in a normal if else sentence in the programming language c?

Tried this

```cpp
// Berechne max von a und b
if (a[0] < b[0]) double max= b[0]; {
else double max = a[0];
}
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: You will need to study _scope_ of variables in your C book.

Answer (score 0):

```
    double max;

    if (a[0] < b[0])
    {
         max= b[0];
    }
    else 
    {
         max = a[0];
    }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?